# For цикл в Lua

Tags: lua

Как организовать такой цикл for в lua?

```
for (t = 0; t < 1 + step; t += step)
```

Делал

```
for t = 0, step + 1, t = t + step do print (test) end
```

не получается, ошибка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

третим параметром должен идти шаг, а не присваивание.  lua сама сделает это.

```
step = 0.1
for t = 0, step + 1, step do
print (t) 
end
```

заковырку вижу только одну - самое последнее значение ( в моем случае это 1.1 по идее не должно попадать в начальном варианте, но оно попадает в lua).

поэтому более правильное

```
step = 0.1
for t = 0, 1, step do
print (t) 
end
```

Но вещественная арифметика она такая, на равенство сравнивать очень опасно вещественные числа.